# Ruby on rails form for postgresql array

Tags: arrays, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

I haven't found any example of how to make a dynamic form for a field which is a Postgresql array.

I want to fill it dynamically using Mustache.js. I have done it before but with a string field using a json string.

I am using ruby2.0, rails4.0 and postgresql9.1.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You can insert the Array values into a form with:

```
<input type = 'textbox' name = 'model[array_column_name][:item_1, :item_2...]'>

params['model']['array_column_name']
```

I'm not familiar with mustache.js but the above should give you a rough understanding on how to implement a form with a PostgreSQL Array.

Comment: sorry to necro bump, but what the heck is type `textbox`? I've never heard of that and can't find any info on it...